# Install poppler using exec() in PHP

Tags: php, linux, exec, poppler

I am very new to using `Linux` commands. I am trying to install `Poppler-Utils` for `Linux` Using this `PHP` code:

```
exec('install poppler > /usr/local/bin/  2>&1', $output);
print_r($output);
```

**Output:**

```
Array ( )
```

- What does this mean?
- Is it the right way to install `Poppler-Utils` on a Linux Server?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I think really not, but wait for more experienced comments. You have access to linux commandline?

Comment: No, I use shared hosting with shell access enabled